# DecodeURIComponent not working for total string

Tags: javascript, decodeuricomponent

This below snippet:
decodeURIComponent("MAR%2520SE%255EStruc%2520Fin%255EAs-Bad%2520Secies%2BRECH%20LANE%5EEnish")

Answer Given:
"MAR%20SE%5EStruc%20Fin%5EAs-Bad%20Secies+RECH LANE^Enish"

I need the entire thing to be decoded right from beginning to end.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your string has been encoded twice.  `%25` is the encode version of `%`.

So either stop encoding it twice, or call decodeURIComponent twice.

`decodeURIComponent( decodeURIComponent("MAR%2520SE%255EStruc%2520Fin%255EAs-Bad%2520Secies%2BRECH%20LANE%5EEnish"))`

Comment: I did this but as the url size increase.. I have to keep adding decodeURIComponent

Comment: `but as the url size increase` show the encoding code

Comment: I have to decode the entire value like
MARKET%2520SECTOR%255EStructured%2520Finance%255EAsset-Backed%2520Securities%2BRESEARCH%20LANGUAGE%5EEnglish, I want to make this entire string decode and send

Comment: @Charan Can you show us the code that is having the issues?  Are you having problems calling it twice?